# How to enable Bootstrap4 tooltips inside an Angular app

Tags: angular, tooltip, bootstrap-4, tether

I'm trying to use Bootstrap4 tooltips in an Angular app built using the Angular CLI.

The Bootstrap4 alpha documentation says that I need to run this command in order to enable tooltips:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

So, I've added a ngAfterViewInit() function in the app.component.ts to do that:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

With this in the app html file:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hi there!">
    Tooltip Test
</button>
```

I do see a tooltip when hovering over the button, but it is just a normal browser tooltip, not a Bootstrap4 tooltip.

At run time, I get the error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Adding this line to the component does not help.

```
declare var $: any;
```

I've double-checked that the jquery, tether, and boostrap js files are included in that order in the scripts section of the project angular-cli.json file.

Any suggestions how I might get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: did u try placing an `id` and use `getElementById` instead of that `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')` ?

Comment: My suggestion: use ng-bootstrap [Tooltip component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install jquery and bootstrap typings to make them available in Typescript and Angular.

For bootstrap `npm install --save @types/bootstrap`
For jquery `npm install --save @types/jquery`

Import bootstrap as shown:
`import 'bootstrap'`

Import jquery this way
`import * as $ from 'jquery'`

Make sure to initialize bootstrap tooltip in `ngAfterViewChecked`
`

```
import 'bootstrap';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
//extras removed for brevity
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  }
}
```

`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure why/how, but this works like a charm! Adding the imports did the trick for me. Thanks

Comment: Reasonable to put this into app.component.ts?

Comment: @pixelpax That is exactly where I would put it.

Answer (score 0):

We implemented Chinemere Okereke's solution (Thank you) and ran into the following error at runtime :

```
ERROR Error: TOOLTIP: Option "sanitizeFn" provided type "window" but expected type "null|function)"
```

And had to add the sanitize: and sanitizeFn: to the .tooltip() call :

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    const $ = $_;
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({sanitize: false, sanitizeFn: content => content});
}
```

Working great!  hope this helps